# How to validation a user input expression, make sure the result is Boolean, and limiting the variable and methods used in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, validation, abstract-syntax-tree

My purpose is to validate if a user input expression is safe, legit and valid. For example, the expression could be:

```
exp = '''((value[0] == "failed" or value[0] == "blocked" or value[0] == "errored") and value[1] == "passed") '''
```

As pointed out by the comment, eval() is not a good way to to validation. Here is my constraints:

- Only the variable 'value' is used in the expression.
- Only a limited number of methos is allowed in the dictionary, for example:

  ```
  safe_methods = ['cos', 'sum', 'sin']
  ```
- The expression must generate a boolean result, either True for False.

The syntax of the expression may be checked by code:

```
st = parser.expr(exp)
```

And check if an parser exception is thrown.
My questions is how apply all these constraints to the expression?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. The result of the expression is the same no matter if it short-circuits or not. The only way the short-circuiting can be a problem is if some parts of your expression have side effects - and if that's the case, your code smells.

Comment: *“My purpose is to validate if a […] expression is valid […] using eval function”* – **Don’t do that**. `eval` should **never** be used on unknown content, especially not if you haven’t validated it before. Calling `eval` is **not** a good way to validate anything. – If you want to validate the syntax, then parse it using the `ast` module. That way you don’t even need to evaluate the expression at all, and you won’t get run-time behavior like short circuiting.

Comment: `eval` is a crutch. If the semantics you want from your expressions don't match the semantics of Python, a Python expression evaluator is the wrong tool for the job. This is especially the case if you want to perform some sort of validation rather than arbitrary code execution.

Comment: @poke You are right. Ast would be the right way to go. Could someone vote to close this post?

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are trying to do is to flag any occurrences of certain tokens in the 'value' array. Something similar to this.

```
def doesContain (token, alist):
  return (token in alist)

flagged=0

value=['failed','passed']

if (doesContain('failed',value)):
    print "contains failed\n"
    flagged+=1

if (doesContain('blocked',value)):
    print "contains blocked\n"
    flagged+=1

if (doesContain('errored',value)):
    print "contains errored\n"
    flagged+=1

if (flagged > 0):
    print ("%s items where flagged\n" % (flagged))
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the ast package to parse the user input, and override the visit function to ensure that only safe methods and variable are used in user input expression. 
In addition, no assignment operator is allowed, to ensure that a boolean variable is returned. First parse the string into an abstract syntax tree using the ast module. The ast is a tree where each node represent an entity like operator, expression in python syntax. The visit() method in ast uses the visitor design patterns, which visit each node up down from the tree, and call the corresponding visit_<>() function by the type of the node. The key here is override the visit_Name and visit_Assign function, so that the criteria is met.

```
import ast
SAFE_LIST = ['sum', 'len', 'max', 'min', 'abs', 'float', 'True', 'False', ' 
    value']
class allnames(ast.NodeVisitor):
    def visit_Module(self, node):
        self.names = set()
        self.assign = False
        self.generic_visit(node)
        for value in self.names:
            if value not in SAFE_LIST:
                return 'Variables other than value is used'
        if self.assign:
            return 'Assignment operator is used'
        return True

    def visit_Name(self, node):
        self.names.add(node.id)

    def visit_Assign(self, node):
        self.assign = True
        self.generic_visit(node)

rule = 'value = 1 or value(3) or ((sum(value) == 1 or value[0] == "failed" or value[0] ==  "blocked" or value[0] == "errored") and value[1] == "passed") or ((value[0] == "failed") and value[1] == "blocked") or ((value[0] == "blocked") and value[1] == "failed") or ((value[0] == "errored") and value[1] == "failed") or ((value[0] == "errored") and value[1] == "blocked")'
t = ast.parse(rule)
print(allnames().visit(t))
```